# Is this the proper way to inform the main thread of an event from a Background thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

The background-thread is an UDP listener. As soon as a certain type of message is received, the main thread has some work to do. 
My current solution works. But I'm in doubt of the implementation.

My question:

- Is this a proper way to handle these "simple" situations?
- Is there another simple and elegant solution that's more commonly accepted?

The server class:

```
class UdpServer
{
    UdpClient listener;

    Messenger messenger;

    public UdpServer(Messenger messenger)
    {
        this.messenger= messenger;
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        listener = new UdpClient(settings.Port);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 15000);

        try
        {
            while(true)
            {
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

                messenger.Message = string.Format("{0} : {1}", 
                    groupEP.ToString(), 
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
            }
        }
        catch(SocketException e)
        {
            messenger.Message = string.Format("UDP server error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thread "safety" is sort of implemented in the way that the thread reading the message will only check the value when the Event has been triggered. The event will only be triggered when the value is completely written. As long as each thread gets its own messenger instance, no trouble with threads sharing variables will arise, right?

The messenger class:

```
//this class is used to transport messages from the receiving threads to the main UI thread.
//subscribe to statusmessageevent in order to receive the messages

class Messenger
{
    private string message;       
    public string Message
    {
        set
        {
            message = value;
            StatusMessageEventHandler(message);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> StatusMessageEvent;
    private void StatusMessageEventHandler(string message)
    {
        StatusMessageEvent?.Invoke(this, message);
    }
}
```

The main thread:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var UdpMessenger = new Messenger();

        UdpMessenger.StatusMessageEvent += MessengerEvent;

        var UdpServer = new UdpServer(UdpMessenger);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UdpServer.StartListening());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    private static void MessengerEvent(object sender, string e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Received Message: {0}", e));
    }
```

Comment: If your code works and you're looking for design or performance improvement, a question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea of the separation between Stack Overflow and CodeReview

Comment: Your design choice of using the Message **property** for an action/behavior is confusing and misleading. A property is more like a field or variable (with potential side-effects that can be implemented in the setter/getter) that in itself should not be used like a method that "does stuff". To make your code less confusing and easier to understand, you should use a method like SendMessage (or another meaningful name) when your code is trying to send a message. `messenger.Message = ...` looks like an ordinary assignment, not like some method call that does some action, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I agree, that would certainly make things more clear. Thank you.

Comment: I was under the impression that because the instance was created on the main thread, the event would be called there too. At least it worked much better than when I tried to raise an event on the background thread. As that lead to very unpredictable behavior. 
However, this was exactly why I posted the question, I'm not sure what would be the proper way to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write in the comments:

> I was under the impression that because the instance was created on the main thread, the event would be called there too.

Objects in C# and .NET are not thread-affine by default. You need to implement this behavior manually. Creating a generic object on a thread doesn't cause that object to raise events on the thread the object was created on. Events are raised on the caller thread, if you don't provide a custom implementation that changes this.

With your current code, the `StatusMessageEvent` events will be raised on the caller thread (the one that runs the `StartListening` method).

If you have a GUI application (e.g. WPF, WinForms), you can manually marshal to the main thread when necessary.

```
class Program
{
    static SynchronizationContext mainThreadContext;

    static void Main()
    {
        // app initialization code here

        // you could also do this somewhere in your main window
        mainThreadContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    static void MessengerEvent(object sender, EventArgs<string> e)
    {
        // do additional stuff here that can be done on a background thread

        // The UpdateUI method will be executed on the UI thread
        mainThreadContext.Post(_ => UpdateUI(), null);
    }

    static void UpdateUI() { }          
}
```

Instead of the `SynchronizationContext`, you can use `Control.BeginInvoke` (WinForms) or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (WPF).

If you have a console app and for some reason need to marshal to the main thread... Well, then you need to implement your own `SynchronizationContext` and something like a task scheduler or a dispatcher or a main loop. That's not easy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer. I just realized I didn't explain one of my main concerns: When firing the event from another thread, is there any risk of the event getting lost?

Comment: @Micha, there is always a risk that an event will be lost, e.g. when your app crashes or when some buffer overflows etc. Consider asking a different question about your case.